# TinyMCE add padding to all images

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce-4

How can we add padding to all images?

I tried to add `content_style: 'img { padding: 5px; }'` which works perfactly in tinyMCE editor. But problem is, we publish the content from our application to wordpress where that styling would not be available and so would not add any padding.

All I have to do is open the source code editor and manually add required styling inline for each image which is very tedious.

Can anybody suggest how can I fix this issue?

P.S. I have added [issue](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues/2516) on github as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More advance options available after adding `image_advtab: true` in configuration.

Reference: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/image/#image_advtab

P.S. You still have to key in `padding` in css input field.